# Standard Quick Actions doesn't show on Case object

Tags: case, publisher-action, global-actions

Im confused - it seems like I can't have standard quick actions on case. Like Change Status and especially important is Email quick actions to be shown on case object in feed view.

Based on the below documentation, this should be true depending on how you interpret (Send email actions, available only on cases, give users access to a simplified version of the Case Feed Email action on Salesforce1.):
(Simplified - Where is the NOT simplified email action located?)
http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/15/en-us/sfdc/pdf/actions_impl_guide.pdf

Please point me in a direction?

Below is a screenshot of global case layout quick actions:
[image]

Below is hovering change status quick actions:
[image]

Below is how it looks in Salesforce:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first things I check when I don't see the quick-actions I expect to see are

1. do I have the permissions to make the change?
2. for create-record actions, is the record type specified on the quick-action one that is assigned to my profile?

It doesn't seem as if the second applies here. But if you are working in a sandbox and you have Email Deliverability set to None or System emails only, then the Email quick-action will disappear from the page. This is true even if you switch Email Deliverability back to All Emails! In other words, switching off deliverability removes the Email quick-action from your layout and you'll have to add it back manually.

About the lack of the Change Status action, I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue with Global action Send Email. which is not visible on chatter publisher layout only for case object. It is visible for other objects. Also when i select global action Send Email I am unable to see Case object in record selection lookup